# Prevent certain group of users from accessing Control Panel using Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, privileges

I can't seem to find a way to prevent *certain groups* of users from Accessing the Control Panel.

It's either disabled for all user or none.

Comment: As long as the users have access to the registry, there is always some way to bypass your block. A simple google search will give them the necessary commands to load any control panel tool.

Answer (score 0):

I could only find a type of work around.
 You could hide the Control Panel Tools, this will hide them in the Start Menu and the Control Panel, his will not stop them working but you and they will have to use the command prompt.
I don't know there skill level but it may work.
 You could also hide only the tools you wish closed.
[To hide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325852)
A list of control panel files is at the bottom of 'To Hide'
[Run control Panel from command prompt](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192806)
Some Methods of Restricting Registry Access:
 Removing executable files from users' workstations
 Using Software Restriction Policies
 Protecting executable files by using file system permissions
 Editing access rights to registry keys
detail at  [flylib.com](http://flylib.com/books/en/1.532.1.59/1/)
Hope something helps.